# Entity Framework persiting record to DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've gone back to Entity framework for a project.
My database relationships are enforced on the database, not just on the business layer.

I'm having a foreign key constraint when I am trying to add a record, that has a new child record just created.

Below is a simple example of my table and codee.

**Main Table**

- Id int (pk)
- ChildId int (fk)
- Name nvarchar(50)

**Child table**
 - Id int (pk) 
 - Name nvarch(50)

```
 private static int addChild(string name)
    {
        using (var context = new DatabaseEntity())
        {
            var table = new DBChildTable() { Name = name };
            context.DBChildTable.Add(table);
            context.SaveChanges();

            return table.Id;

        }
    }

    private static int addMain(int childId, string name)
    {
        using (var context = new DatabaseEntity())
        {
            var table = new DBMainTable() { Name = name, ChildId = childId };
            context.DBMainTable.Add(table);
            context.SaveChanges();

            return table.Id;

        }
    }

    private static void basiceLogic()
    {
        int childId = addChild("Child");
        addMain(childId, "Main");
    }
```

I am using Entity framework 6 and a SQL server back end database.

I do remember, that I needed to add a command to the context or somewhere to tell the code to persist the record from the in memory Entity framework to the database.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: What your question about? Code you shared should work.

Comment: SaveChanges() is the command :)

Comment: Hi, I know.  When I go the the second method to add the main elements, it complains about the  foreign key constraint on the childId.  But if run the method again, using the childId from the first attempt, it works.

Comment: The SaveChanges(), should work.  But for some reason the child is not seen within the db, when the main record is being Saved.

Comment: You create a new DBMainTable there, but only set the FK, not the navigation property. Therefore no child will be added and in a correctly configured database a referential integrity constraint will be violated.

Comment: This works if the child is already within the DB. It doesn't work, If I have created the child at the same time within the method.  
For example, If I do a post and create the child. Then do a second post and create the mainTable record, with the child created in the first post.  The main record is inserted, no problem.  I've not needed to set any navigation prop in runtime.

Comment: Is your Context Initializer DropCreateDatabaseAlways?

Comment: Hi DevilSuichiro, I've created my EF from the database and I have not changed any of the default settings.  But, since you've asked this question I have added Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<blogEntity>()); and context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; to the code, but no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending too long on this issue and going back and forth between forums, I have finally found a result.

Below is code that I had to alter to get it to work, but now it works.  (The code used is the the code within the example)

I needed to add a dispose and recreate of the context.  Even though I originally had the context within a using and a static method logic, the context did not really dispose.  So the new database record would not persist into the db, before it was queried within the second insert.

Thanks to all that has attempted to help, but thought I would put up my resolve just incase there, someone else out there that is having the this nice little issue.

```
private static Models.Blog.blogEntity context;
    public static string AddComment(int blogId, string email, string name, string comment)
    {
        context = new Models.Blog.blogEntity();                
        string blogName = String.Empty;

        blogName = Models.Blog.Queries.BlogQuery.NameById(blogId);

        getUserId(email);

        createUser(email, name);

        context.Dispose();
        context = new Models.Blog.blogEntity();

        createComment(blogId, userId, comment);

        context.Dispose();
        return blogName;

    }


    private static void getUserId(string email)
    {
        userId = 0;
        var user = context.users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.emailAddress.Equals(email));
        if(user !=null)
        {
            userId = user.id;
        }
    }

    public static void createUser(string emailAddress, string name)
    {
        if(userId.Equals(0))
        {
            var data = new Models.Blog.user()
            {
                emailAddress = emailAddress,
                name = name,
                password = "NOT NEEDED",
                userlevel = 0,
                created = DateTime.Now
            };
            context.users.Add(data);
            context.SaveChanges();                
            userId = data.id; 
        }        


    }

    public static void createComment(int blogId, int userId, string comment)
    {           

        var data = new Models.Blog.comment()
        {
            body = comment,
            blogId = blogId,
            createdBy = userId,
            created = DateTime.Now
        };
        context.comments.Add(data);
        context.SaveChanges();
        commentId= data.id;           
    }
```